# Unknown encoding used in PDF strings

Tags: pdf, character-encoding

I am writing code to extract URLs from PDF files. In most files, the URLs appear as plain ascii. However, in some PDF files, such as the PDF specification itself (https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) the URLs appear in hexadecimal form with seemingly no structure.

For example, in the above file, in the main metadata, the author appears as:

`/Author <F240D629CD72348F>`

This is decoded by Atril and other PDF viewers as "Jim King". The hexadecimal strings are double the length of the literal value as expected, but scrambled beyond recognition. Assuming a 1:1 mapping of byte value to characters, the "i" is encoded both as 0x40 and 0x72.

Actual URL value:
`<EB345AA632781A90E90781A4A0BF42680D1F1AD67910B293798B0AFFED8407CE12684F21B7F471D96DCE4864CAB970A98E7F911C207A12C6E6900D789BC13AE87E76A9D6B8EDDADE7A53EAA521E6421295EA31305C>`

Should decode to:
`http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=51502`

I have also looked at PyPDF2 source code which manages to decode these strings, but I have not found the answer.

How do I find the encoding used for annotations in a PDF document ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example pdf is encrypted as you can determine by looking at its trailer which contains an **Encrypt** entry:

```
/Encrypt 126988 0 R
```

Thus, all strings and streams in that pdf (with a very few exceptions) are encrypted.

(If you wonder why you don't have to enter a password when opening the file: the pdf standard defines a default password which a pdf processor tries before asking the user to supply a password. This default password is used here.)

Thus, before analyzing the strings you have to decrypt them. If you don't want to implement the decryption yourself, you can use a tool like qpdf to do that in preparation for your code.